# Producing a PDF file with "CID TrueType" fonts

Tags: fonts, ghostscript, postscript

I'm looking for a step-by-step guide to create a PDF file with sample text, referencing fonts of type "CID TrueType", while not having those fonts embedded.

For context, I'm debugging a production issue related to processing an actual PDF file. The file allegedly was produced by some software for generating reports. The PDF file in question has the following font situation:

```
$ pdffonts broken.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times New Roman,Bold                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       no  no  yes      3  0
Times New Roman,Bold                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       no  no  yes      4  0
Times New Roman                      CID TrueType      Identity-H       no  no  yes      5  0
Times New Roman                      CID TrueType      Identity-H       no  no  yes     10  0
Arial,Bold                           CID TrueType      Identity-H       no  no  yes     11  0
$
```

Unfortunately, since this file is from an actual customer, it's not possible to easily share the file around, even among co-workers.

Thus, before even getting to solving actual challenges such a file poses for our application, I am looking for a way to create a "minimal reproduction" PDF example that I can easily share around. Such sample file should sufficiently mimic the original PDF file in terms of fonts.

I've came up with the following `sample.ps`:

```
%!PS
/Arial
20 selectfont
72 700 moveto
(A summer river being crossed) show

/Times-Roman
20 selectfont
72 650 moveto
(how pleasing) show

/Times-Bold
20 selectfont
72 600 moveto
(with sandals in my hands!) show
showpage
```

However, a PDF produced from this `sample.ps` lists all fonts as `Type 1` or `TrueType`, but not as `CID TrueType`:

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEmbedAllFonts=false -o output.pdf sample.ps
# ...
Loading ArialMT font from /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Arial.ttf... 5145024 3571205 11691560 8060049 1 done.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/10.01.2/share/ghostscript/10.01.2/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 5206968 3755189 11733704 8112801 1 done.
Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/10.01.2/share/ghostscript/10.01.2/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold... 5313448 3956352 11733704 8116398 1 done.
$
```

```
$ pdffonts output.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Roman                          Type 1            Standard         no  no  no       9  0
Times-Bold                           Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      10  0
Arial                                TrueType          Standard         no  no  yes      7  0
$
```

Any tips or pointers for how to mimic the original file?

Comment: You will find it very difficult to do this starting from PostScript, I'm doubtful it is possible. Your best bet is to get a PDF file which already has CIDFonts in it, and remove the FontFile entries from Font Descriptor dictionaries. Or, as K J says, overwrite the character codes with 'something else' in your original file. Note that CIDFonts are **supposed** to be embedded in PDF files, and if they are not then a substitute must be used. The only thing you can say about the result is that it will be 'wrong' in some sense. Maybe legible, but not guaranteed, certainly the wrong rendered shapes

Comment: The attachment to this bug report https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=694353 is a PDF file with a TrueType CIDFont (CIDFontType2) which is not embedded and not subset. The font is UniversLTStd45Light,Bold (and the combination of Light and Bold in the name says it all, really).  The font in question is used above the address at top right, and displayed by Acrobat as a series of dots. Ghostscript displays it as 'HANSEN PRODUCTS'.

Comment: @KenS thanks so much! Feel free to post a an answer pointing to the said file, I will make sure to accept it

Comment: I will follow-up with another question, this time a more specific one based on the file in question. The question is regarding the CID font substitution. Will tag you two, to see if you have ideas about how to do it

Comment: @oldhomemovie, I don't post answers any more :-) I'm glad you found the file of some use though.

Comment: @KenS thanks again! May I ask what made you decide to not post answers anymore? 

Comment: I had a run-in with the site moderators. There's no record of it because the moderators deleted the whole thread.